# How to create clickable map for iPhone

Tags: ios, maps

Since the iPhone doesn't support Flash, how do you create clickable maps with hotspots or zones that change colour with a mouseover event?

Like this Flash mp here.

http://www.usflashmap.com/samples/real-estate-map/index_ext.html

Answer (score 2):

Rest assured that you don't have a mouseover event in Mobile Safari. In fact, it's inherent to the use of a touch screen.

Comment: Well I meant touch up inside or whatever you'd like to use. Actually I wasn't talking about Safari either. I was talking about an app that has a map and when you click a place the next 'View' is that place.

You're right anyway even in an app. You can't rollover only touch. So I guess I'd like that place to light up a different colour for 0.20 seconds then move to the next View.

Comment: The browser on the iPhone is Mobile Safari, so actually I wasn't talking about Safari either.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using html as the output format a lib like [RaphaelJs](http://raphaeljs.com/) could help you. Got something like this in the examples

Answer (score 0):

How about the good old `<map>` tag? http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp